# Getting error in express.js and node.js code the error :- GET /images/uploads/ 404 3.524 ms - 1443

Tags: node.js, express

here in div conatiner cards the image tag there i am facing problem with accessing the image from the public/images/uploads there the profile image and post image both are present but i am not able to load the post image

```
<%- include('./partials/header.ejs') %>
    <div class="containerpre">
      <div class="cardpre">
          <form hidden id="uploadform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/fileupload">
            <input type="file" name="image" id="imageInput" onchange="document.querySelector('#uploadform').submit();">
            <label for="imageInput" class="button">Upload Image</label>
          </form>
        <div class="relative" id="uploadicon">
          <div class="profile-picture relative">
              <img src="/images/uploads/<%= user.profileImage %>" alt="">
          </div>
            <span id="uploadicon" onclick="document.querySelector('#uploadform input[type=\'file\']').click();">
                <i class="profile-pict bg-zinc-500 ri-pencil-fill"></i>
            </span>
        </div>
        <h2 class="name"><%= user.name%></h2>
        <h3 class="username">@<%= user.username %></h3>
        <p class="tagline">Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing.</p>
        <p class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Voluptatem.</p>
        <a href="/add" class="button bg-red-700 hover:bg-red-700 ">Add New Post</a>
      </div>
      <div class="cards flex flex-wrap gap-10 px-10 mt-10">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="w-52 h-40 bg-zinc-200 rounded-lg overflow-hidden">
            <img class="w-full h-full object-cover" src="/images/uploads/<%user.posts[0].image%>" alt="User Post Image">
          </div>
          <a href="/show/posts" class="text-xl font-semibold mt-3">Your Uploaded Pins</a>
          <h5 class="text-sm font-medium opacity-60"><%= user.posts.length %> Pins</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
<%- include('./partials/footer.ejs') %>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Krppj.png)
not able to upload it
Btw its a pinterest clone

Comment: What do you get when you output `/images/uploads/<%= user.profileImage %>` ?

Comment: i get the image which i uploaded for profile and its the desire output only ... but error is coming in the  <%user.posts[0].image%> in it no image is displayed